# How to join 2 columns in the same table hierarchical data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table UserType

| ID | UserType | ChildUserType |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Customer | null |
| 2 | Sale | Customer |
| 3 | Manager | Sale |
| 4 | SuperAdmin | Admin |
| 5 | Admin | Manager |

...

How can I Query for example let say  UserType = SuperAdmin show result

| UserType |
| --- |
| Admin |
| Manager |
| Sale |
| Customer |

UserType = Manager show result

| UserType |
| --- |
| Sale |
| Customer |

Thanks

Comment: First, you need to tag the type of sql you are using for us to help you. Secondly, you need to explain what exactly the logic is behind what you want as a result.

Comment: hi  
Ineffable21
Im using sql server, the result would be a table shown, im using StoreProc

Comment: Tag the type of sql you are using, because a lot of people don't even bother opening questions that aren't tagged properly, so a lot of people that know how to help you, won't even see your question. About the result, I understand that the second and third tables are expected result depending on the UserType, but what makes them the expected result? For example, when you want to get 'Sale' and 'Customer' when UserType = Manager, why would you expect those 2 results? Is it because the childUserType of Manager is Sale, and the ChildUserType of Sale is Customer, and then it stops when null?

Comment: sorry for tagged unproperly.  And Yes, if they are manager role  they can only see Customer and sale

Comment: I think i forgot add Id Column in the result table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm checking your request, I think the follows query is the result are as you expected, the query was update to follows your rule chain parent and child register

```
WITH table1  AS (
    SELECT * FROM (
    VALUES
        (1,'Customer', ''), 
        (2,'Sale', 'Customer'), 
        (3,'Manager', 'Sale'), 
        (4,'SuperAdmin', 'Admin'),
        (5,'Admin', 'Manager')
    ) AS _ (ID,UserType,ChildUserType)
),
Table2 AS (
    SELECT ID
       ,UserType
       ,ChildUserType
    FROM table1
    WHERE UserType = 'SuperAdmin' --Update this variable to get the result

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
       t1.ID
       ,t1.UserType
       ,t1.ChildUserType
    FROM
       table1 t1
       INNER JOIN Table2 T2
       ON t1.UserType = T2.ChildUserType
)
SELECT ChildUserType as UserType
FROM Table2  where Len(ChildUserType) > 0
```

The result query where Usertype = SuperAdmin

```
UserType
Admin
Manager
Sale
Customer
```

The result query where Usertype = Manager

```
UserType
Sale
Customer
```

Best Regards

Comment: Thanks Diego, I special put SuperAdmin before Admin, the reason for that, that I could add more roles later on.   for example Id 6  'Manager','staff'

Comment: hi, understood was intentional, I think with that you will have to define many rules in your query to take the expected result, I don't know if you could change, is just another suggestion, also you could create a table example UserTypeProfileList where there we have two column what could be UserTypeParent and UserType and register in that table all the usertype what should list by one usertyparent, this table you can use composite primary key and the query will be simple like " select usertype FROM UserTypeProfileList WHERE userTypeParent = 'SuperAdmin' " that could be another aproach,regards

Comment: hi Diego, yes you are right, but reason I do not want create table is because every time when I need new ChildUsertype i aslo need create new table for that ChildUsertype. that would be many tables

Comment: hi Huy, so I did the update on source code, could you please check it if now works well, take a look when you can, best regards